# How to get nearest key index in associative JavaScript array if key does not exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable, associative-array

So, this might be a weird thing to try to do, but I'm curious if it's possible:

Say I have an associative array like this:

```
myarray[50] = 'test1'  
myarray[100] = 'test2'
```

I can access `'test1'` by it's key, of course:

```
myarray[50]; // returns 'test1'
```

**But is there a way where if I have an index key of '60', that I can look in the array and if key 60 *isn't* there, get the value of the next "closest" key, '50'?**

The use-case for this is that I am trying to set up cue-points for a video, and if the user seeks and misses a cue point, I want to display the information from the last cue point the user seeked beyond.

I think I can check for the existence of the key with the 'in' operator. But if it's not found, how can I get the "previous" or "next smallest" array key that DOES exist?

I assume the only way to do this is to iterate through the array, saving the "last" index value until the exit condition of "index > myKey" is found. The thing is, if it's a long video with lots of queue points and the user seeks frequently, iterating through the entire array of cue points each time might be slow. Is there a better, faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to write your own function:

```
function getClosestTo(val, array) {
    if (array[val] !== undefined) {
        return val;
    } else {
        var upper = val;
        var upperMatched = false;
        var lower = val;
        var lowerMatched = false;

        while(upper < this.length) {
            if (array[++upper] !== undefined) {
                upperMatched = true;
                break;
            };
        };

        while(lower > -1) {
            if (array[--lower] !== undefined) {
                lowerMatched = true;
                break;
            };
        };

        if (upperMatched && lowerMatched) {
            return upper - val < val - lower ? upper : lower;
        } else if (upperMatched) {
            return upper;
        } else if (lowerMatched) {
            return lower;
        };
    };

    return -1;
};
```

You could also add this as a method of the Array prototype, to make (what I think) is more readable:

```
Array.prototype.getClosestTo = function (val) {
    if (this[val] !== undefined) {
        return val;
    } else {
        var upper = val;
        var upperMatched = false;
        var lower = val;
        var lowerMatched = false;

        while(upper < this.length) {
            if (this[++upper] !== undefined) {
                upperMatched = true;
                break;
            };
        };

        while(lower > -1) {
            if (this[--upper] !== undefined) {
                lowerMatched = true;
                break;
            };
        };

        if (upperMatched && lowerMatched) {
            return upper - val < val - lower ? upper : lower;
        } else if (upperMatched) {
            return upper;
        } else if (lowerMatched) {
            return lower;
        };
    };

    return -1;
};

// Usage: 
// var closestKey = theArray.getClosestTo(50);
```

Comment: Just what I suspected, but thanks for the tips! I would not have thought of putting that in the Array prototype, but it would be slick that way!